# Fullcalendar prevent selection onto next day

Tags: fullcalendar

In my fullcalendar instance (2.6.1) I want to prevent a user from selecting an event over multiple days. I have been looking at the documentation, but I can't seem to find an option to disable that behaviour. My configuration looks like this.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    // General display
    header: false,
    weekends: true,
    height: $('#container').height(),

    // Views
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',

    // Selection
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,

    // Text/Time Customization
    lang: 'nl',
    columnFormat: {
        day: 'D dddd',
        week: 'D dddd'
    },

    // Agenda options
    minTime: '07:30:00',
    maxTime: '18:30:00',
    allDaySlot: false,
    slotDuration: '00:30:00',
    slotEventOverlap: false,
    snapDuration: '00:15:00',
    slotLabelFormat: 'H.mm',
    slotLabelInterval: "00:30:00",

    // Event data
    allDayDefault: false,

    // Event Dragging & Resizing
    editable: true,
    dragOpacity: 1,
    eventConstraint: {
        start: '07:30:00',
        end: '18:30:00'
    },


});
```

I was hoping that `minTime` and `maxTime` would do the trick, but apparently not.

How would I got about achieving this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I have found a way to prevent the rendering of the event, with the following callback:

```
// Callbacks
select: function( start, end, jsEvent, view) {
    // If the selection spans multiple day
    if ( ! end.isAfter(start, 'day')) {
        window.calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
            start: start,
            end: end,
            allDay: false
        }, true);
    }

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
}
```

However, this does not prevent you from dragging the selection onto the next day all together.

Comment: This was a big help to me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`selectConstraint` will helpful to prevent drag to different date.
Below is example you can refer.

> $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
>               header: {
>                   left: 'title',
>                   center: '',
>                   right: ''
>               },
>          events: events, 
>         **selectConstraint: {   // This will stop to drag for multiple days
>                   start: '00:01',
>                   end: '23:59',
>               }**
>       });

I am referring FullCalendar v2.8.0 version.

Comment: Currently this still works with startTime & endTime (instead of start & end)

Answer (score 0):

Use **eventConstraint**:

```
eventConstraint:{
                start: '07:00:00',
                end: '22:00:00'
            },
```

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventConstraint